# Get contact details from contact id in Android

Tags: android, list, lookup, contacts

I want to get several contact details from a contact list view. I have this code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long id) {
        //HERE I WANT TO GET CONTACT DETAILS FROM THE ID PARAMETER

        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(id));
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null,null,null);
        try {
              c.moveToFirst();
              String displayName = c.getString(0);
        } finally {
              c.close();
        }

}
```

But I get this exception: IllegalArgumentException, Invalid lookup id (when I call query method from cursor).
So I dont know how to get a valid lookup id from the item list.

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here `id` means, A `contact id` for which you want to fetch the contact details,

The simply code for getting phone number for a particular `contact id` is like,

```
                    // Build the Uri to query to table
                    Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);

                    // Query the table
                    Cursor phoneCursor = managedQuery(
                            myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);

                    // Get the phone numbers from the contact
                    for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

                        // Get a phone number
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        sb.append("Phone: " + phoneNumber + "\n");
                    }
                }
```

So, from your question I have to doubt for id parameter which are you sing in your uri just clear that, Also in my example the id is string type...

Hope you will understand it.

**Update:** `Uri.encode(id)` instead of just pass **id in string format**.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Because `managedQuery` is deprecated you can also use

```
Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int columnIndex = arg2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

private void retriveContactImage(ImageView imageView, int columnIndex) {
    Bitmap photo = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(columnIndex)));
        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
}

private ArrayList<String> retrieveContactNumbers(TextView textView, long contactId) {
    ArrayList<String> phoneNum = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId + "" }, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // store the numbers in an array
            String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (str != null && str.trim().length() > 0) {
                phoneNum.add(str);
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    textView.setText(phoneNum.get(0));
    return phoneNum;
}

private void retrieveContactName(TextView textView, long contactId) {
    String contactName = null;

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    cursor.close();
    textView.setText(contactName);
}
```